# PDO Getting Multiple Values

Tags: php, pdo

Well I've decided to use PDO since I saw some people said that it's better than mysql.

I have this code that should get the uid, ticket_id, and event table.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT embedded_page.uid, embedded_page.ticket_id, embedded_page.event_table FROM embedded_page WHERE fbp_id = :fbp_id");
$query->bindValue(":fbp_id", $fbp_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

echo $compibot_user = $query->fetchObject()->uid;
echo $ticket_id = $query->fetchObject()->ticket_id;
echo $event_table = $query->fetchObject()->event_table;
```

Looking at the code, I echo the three variables **$compibot_user**, **$ticket_id**, and **$event_table**

The result I only got is "**1**" which is the result of **$compibot_user**

$ticket_id and $event_table didn't echo anything. So I've been wondering why isn't it working or so. Any solutions for this stuff?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that every time you `fetchObject()` it picks the NEXT object, so instead you should save the result of `fetchObject()` to a variable, and then refer to the variable. (`$object = $query->fetchObject()` and `$compibot_user = $object->uid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT `embedded_page`.`uid`, `embedded_page`.`ticket_id`, `embedded_page`.`event_table` FROM `embedded_page` WHERE `fbp_id` = ?');
$query->execute(array($fbp_id));

while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
   echo $row['uid'], ', ', $row['ticket_id'], ', ', $row['event_table'];
}
```

Comment: this is not apparently simplest one `while($row = $query->fetch()) echo implode(",",$row);` would be much simpler yet more flexible.

Comment: Bad solution, @YourCommonSense, that would result in a double of each field because the default fetch mode is PDO::FETCH_BOTH.

Comment: you can always override default setting

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT embedded_page.uid, embedded_page.ticket_id, embedded_page.event_table FROM embedded_page WHERE fbp_id = ?";        
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql) or die("Prepare Error");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $fbp_id);       
$stmt->execute();   

$result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo  $result['YOUR COLUMN NAME']; //example echo $result['ticket_id']; 

$stmt->closeCursor();
$stmt=NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that, perhaps:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT embedded_page.uid, embedded_page.ticket_id, embedded_page.event_table FROM embedded_page WHERE fbp_id = :fbp_id");
$query->execute( array( 'fbp_id' => $fbp_id ) );
list ( $compibot_user, $ticket_id, $event_table ) = $query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_NUM );

print "$compibot_user, $ticket_id, $event_table\n";
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense handy, but probably not the best coding style.

Comment: it's apparently best for this very case as it let's you to write field names only **once**, not twice. why repeat yourself?